# Why was this question protected before it was even answered?

Tags: discussion, protected-questions

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31202244/surround-hebrew-text-and-english-text-in-div) was protected 25 minutes after it was asked, before it had any answers and while there was just a brief discussion going on.

Why would this be done?

Comment: I've seen this happen sometimes when a spammer is targeting a specific question.

Comment: Is there any way to view history on this?

Comment: There were deleted answers (from a low rep user), before the question was protected.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There are two answers from the same < 10 rep user, one with a -1 score, then deleted by the OP, then they made another answer shortly after, then self-deleted that. That triggered Community to protect the question to avoid that user trying the same again.

**Update**: The question has been unprotected as it's no longer required.

Comment: That seems kind of an over-reaction on Community's part in this case. Maybe she's feeling under the weather

Comment: @Pekka웃 it may seem a bit blunt - but the < 10 rep user can always undelete and edit a post - it's mostly to stop the question being answer flooded where someone just deletes and reposts instead of editing...

Comment: @Pekka웃 actually, more than 3 <10 rep users answering in less than 24 hours will trigger the protection, which if I recall correctly was a very effective limit considering history of answer deletions.

Comment: @Braiam that wasn't the case here, though, it was one < 10 user answering twice

Comment: @Pekka웃 What weather please?I mean, **WHERE**? The globe is round.

Comment: @SQLPolice I think the SE servers are all over USA. So, let's say, Colorado.